# How to determine the accumulated number of shares bought for a Trade?

Tags: excel, vba

I trade shares on Nasdaq and have unique trade numbers for each trade. Each unique trade number comprises of a number of share purchase transactions.

I am trying to calculate the number of shares that I bought for each unique  trade number and allocate the accumulated number for each share purchase transaction to the adjacent column.

For example: Column A all the Trade Numbers are listed in sequence, Column B the number of Shares bought. I am trying to determine the accumulated number of shares that I have bought for each trade and place the result in Column C.

| Trade Number | Number Shares Bought | Accumulated Number of Shares Bought |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | None | Must be blank |
| 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 2 | None | Must be blank |
| 2 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 3 | 4 |
| 2 | None | Must be blank |

I created the following code. The IF statements do not produce the required output under Column C.

```vb
Sub SequentialShareNumber()

' ' SequentialShareNumber Macro ' Macro allocates a sequential number to each Share bought in a Trade

'Step 1: Declare variables Dim TradeRange As Range Dim TradeCell As Range

'Step 2: Define the Target Range Set TradeRange = Range("A2:A100")

'Step 3: Start looping through the range For Each TradeCell In TradeRange

'Step 4: If TradeCell.Value > 0 Then TradeCell.Select Dim ShareCounter As Integer ShareCounter = 0

'Step 5: Check if a Share was bought for this Trade Number in Column B TradeCell.Offset(0, 1).Range("A1").Select ActiveCell.Select

         If ActiveCell.Value = 1 Then
 
'Step 6: Allocate a sequential number to each Share bought for this Trade Number ShareCounter = ShareCounter + 1

'Step 7: Insert the sequential value in Column C ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Range("A1").Select ActiveCell.value = ShareCounter

        End If

End If
'Step 8: Get the next cell in the range Next TradeCell

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Few things to note:

1. Full qualify your code
2. Avoid using select, you can perform most operation using range (read [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba) for more details)

   ```
   Sub SequentialShareNumber()
       Dim shareCounter As Long
       Dim tradeNumber As Long

       Const rowStart As Long = 2 'Starting row
       Const rowEnd As Long = 1000 'Ending row

       Dim i As Long
       Dim n As Long

       With Sheet1 'Change to the correct worksheet reference
           For i = rowStart To rowEnd  'Loop from row 2 to 1000
               If .Cells(i, 2).Value > 0 Then
                   tradeNumber = .Cells(i, 1).Value
                   For n = 2 To i ' Loop from starting row to the current for calculation
                       If .Cells(n, 1).Value = tradeNumber Then shareCounter = shareCounter + .Cells(n, 2).Value
                   Next n
                   .Cells(i, 3).Value = shareCounter
                   shareCounter = 0
               End If
           Next i
       End With
   End Sub
   ```

Comment: Awesome. Thank you Raymond for the neat approach.